# Bitmap to uint hex array representation for arduino printer

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino

I'm using a web service to convert a pdf to [bitmap](http://%20https://res.cloudinary.com/dlgl1iw3m/image/upload/e_grayscale,w_350/v1521072422/isneoprcgq9ef1k57qgg.bmp) to print on an [Arduino mini thermal printer](https://www.adafruit.com/product/597).

The arduino BMP function requires the bitmap to be an array of type uint8_t. I can bring the BMP down in base64 encoding, so my question is how do I convert a base64 string to an array of equivalent type uint8_t?

```
let buffer = new Buffer(body, 'base64').toString('hex');
let array = [...buffer];

arr = arr.map(e => { return `0x${e.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)}`; });
```

I want to offload as much as possible to the server so that the arduino doesn't have to handle this, so I return this json in the response:

```
let obj = {
    width: img.width, // from cloudinary response (pdf to bmp)
    height: img.height, // from cloudinary response (pdf to bmp)
    data: arr
};
```

But this whole the response is invalid. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I assume it has something to do with my conversion to base64, hex, and then converting the range of characters to hex.

**Update**
I believe I'm getting closer:

```
let buffer = new Buffer(body, 'base64');
let arrBuffer = [...buffer];
let imgArray = new Uint8Array([...arrBuffer], 0, arrBuffer.length);
let hexArray = [];
for (data of imgArray.values()) { hexArray.push(data.toString(16)); }
```

Comment: Why this horribly unnecessarily convoluted conversion? If I understand this correctly you are converting 1 byte into 14 bytes.

Comment: Are you saying the elements in arr is enough?

Comment: If `body` is base64 encoded, then `body` is enough.

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear in my original post. My question is how do I convert a base64 string into an array of equivalent type uint8_t? I've updated according.

Comment: @DarthVadar123451 Did you found the solution at the end?I am facing the same problem